# Save every second line of a file into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to save each second line of a text file into a different element in list. I have studied multiple threads but i need a way so as to use this list and pick a random element from this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, including input, output, expected output and any errors you may encounter

Comment: [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) might be useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Comprehension as way to solve this:

```
l = [line for i, line in enumerate(open('list.txt')) if i % 2 == 1 ]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allows you to skip rows according to a function. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file, excluding even rows
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', skiprows=lambda x: (x+1)%2 == 0)

# convert to list
df_list = df.values.tolist()
```

This will return a list with elements relating to even lines from the input file.

Comment: something is wrong with the "x:" cause i am getting a syntax error.

Comment: It works for me on `pandas` 0.20.3.